# populating word template with python .merge() but TypeError: merge() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script that will take in user info and populate word templates with the information.

I keep getting the following error and I don't understand why:

```
TypeError: merge() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

My script begins by gathering information from the user and storing it into a dictionary. then the following code is executed:

```
stress_notes_document = MailMerge(os.path.join(new_path,new_notes))
stress_notes_document.merge(
        TR_num = packet_info['TR#'],
        pckg_num = packet_info['Package#'],
        TED_num = packet_info['TED#'],
        Charge_Line = packet_info['Charge Line'],
        Change_num = packet_info['Change#'],
        Installation_list  = packet_list['Installations list'],
        Drawings_list   = packet_list['Drawings list'],
        Designer  = packet_info['Designer'],
        phone_number_designer = packet_info['Phone Number of designer'],
        Date_in = packet_info['Date in'],
        Stress_Due_Date = packet_info['Stress Due Date'],
        Date_out = packet_info['Date out'],
        model = packet_info['model'],
        Customer = packet_info['Customer'],
        Effectivity  = packet_info['Effectivity'],
        panel_excel = 'new_panel')

stress_notes_document.write(os.path.join(new_path,new_notes + "ver A"))
```

The error happens when I try to execute the second line, `stress_notes_document.merge(..)`. I am trying to assign a value from my dictionary to a mergefield in the word document.

Any suggestions?

edit: I am using this as a guide: http://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html
The examples shown they use strings in the `merge()` function.

Here is the full error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e67354559525>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Python_All/python_scripts/data_gather.py', wdir='C:/Python_All/python_scripts')

  File "C:\Python_All\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python_All\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Python_All/python_scripts/data_gather.py", line 114, in <module>
    Effectivity  = packet_info['Effectivity'])

  File "C:\Python_All\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mailmerge.py", line 176, in merge
    self.merge_rows(field, replacement)

  File "C:\Python_All\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mailmerge.py", line 219, in merge_rows
    self.merge([row], **row_data)

TypeError: merge() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: I am not getting error you have. I removed references to dicts though (as I don't have them). But it works. Can you try just plain key-values to see whether this works?
I converted it like this:
stress_notes_document = MailMerge('test.docx')
stress_notes_document.merge(
        TR_num = 'TR#',
        pckg_num = 'Package#', ..........

Comment: So what happened is one of the values you passes Is actually a list not a string. If they all were strings this would work. So one (or more) of the packet_info or packet_list elements you use has value which is list. I suggest you print content of these dictionaries to find it. You can use pprint.pprint() print command for this (make sure to 'import pprint').

Comment: @IvanGutierrez your error does not match your code; the error says that there is `Effectivity  = packet_info['Effectivity'])` on line 114, but the code you showed does not have the closing parenthesis after `packet_info['Effectivity']`.

Comment: @Eduard thank you, that Is what was wrong. my dictionary packet_list is all lists. I can change the code to  packet_list['Installations list'][0] so that it uses only the first item in the list and it works. Now if I needed to print all of the items on the list and idk the size of the list how can I pass the list to the merge() function?

Comment: @IvanGutierrez, well this depens on what you want as output. You can join list (",".join(yourlist)) then all values will be in one field. Or you can loop over lists and make a merge per element.

Comment: @IvanGutierrez, does my answer below answers your question? if yes, please mark it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that one of parameter values you pass to `merge()` is a list not a string.

`merge()` as described [in the docs](https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/) enables you to pass list of dictionaries as a shortcut to `merge_rows()` function. So if you pass code as below (taken from docs) then it runs `merge_rows()` function using given list.

```
document.merge(field1='docx Mail Merge',
               col1=[
                   {'col1': 'A'},
                   {'col1': 'B'},
               ])
```

Now, in your code one of the values you provide (packet_list['Installations list'] from comments) is a list, so `merge()` decides to run `merge_rows` on that. But format of your list does not match the expected format (expected format is list with dictionaries as elements, but in your code elements are strings). Thus you get error, when `merge_rows` tries to read provided data as dictionary.

To fix this you either convert list packet_list['Installations list'] into a string, for example:

```
",".join(packet_list['Installations list'] )
```

or convert that list into expected *list of dictionaries* format. 
Whichever makes sense.